# Add a different class to each foreach item

Tags: php, module, joomla-3.4

Using the mod_articles_categories module. I am writing an override but want to add a class to each li within foreach().

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
<li>
```

How can I add a class to the li?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have numbered classes, (someclass_0, someclass_1 etc) you can use something like this:

```
foreach ($list as $key =>$item) : ?>
    <li class="someclass_<?php echo $key  ?>">
...
```

Comment: Always glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
<?php
foreach ($list as $item=>$key) : ?>
<li class="sample_<?php echo $key; ?>"> </li>
<?php end foreach ?>
```